# Changing default values of ANNIE resources in GATE from Java code

Tags: nlp, java

In GATE, default values for ANNIE are set during initialization, but sometimes based on requirements they have to be changed.

**My Requirement** : I want to extract English sentences without considering the "nextline character" but considering "full stop" which gives correct sentences. For that, I need to change the default value of *transducerURL* in SentenceSplitter in ANNIE.
This can be done in two ways:

1. Using *ANNIE_with_defaults.gapp* - changing initparams value in Sentencesplitter and accessing from java:

   ```
    Gate.setGateHome(new File(Configuration.GATE_HOME));                        
    Gate.init();
    // Load ANNIE with defaults from the plug-ins folder
    File pluginsHome = Gate.getPluginsHome();
    File anniePlugin = new File(pluginsHome, ANNIEConstants.PLUGIN_DIR);
    File annieGapp = new File(anniePlugin, ANNIEConstants.DEFAULT_FILE);
    annieController = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(annieGapp);
   ```

**I am not being able to find where to change its value in gapp file.**

2. After initialising GATE, accessing ResourceData using CreoleRegister and changing the default value of parameter *transducerURL* as shown below:

   ```
    String resourceClassName = "gate.creole.splitter.SentenceSplitter";
    ResourceData resData = Gate.getCreoleRegister().get(resourceClassName);
    //System.out.println(resData.getParameterList());
    ParameterList params = resData.getParameterList();
    List<List<Parameter>> param =  params.getInitimeParameters();
    System.out.println(param);
    //System.out.println(param.get(0));
    for(List<Parameter> plist : param)
    {
        for(Parameter pm : plist)
        {
            System.out.println("Name : "+pm.getName()+", "+pm.getDefaultValue());
        }
    }
   ```

**But Parameter does not have `setDefaultvalue` method.**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For any of these situations the best approach is to construct the application as you need it using GATE Developer, "save application state" to create your own custom gapp file, then pass your new gapp to the `PersistenceManager` instead of loading the standard `ANNIE_with_defaults`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @Ian. But I want this in production, no options of creating custom gapp file.

Comment: @Rana my suggestion _is_ for production.  We always recommend you build your app in the GUI and load the saved state in your production code using `PersistenceManager`, it's much less error-prone than trying to construct the pipeline by hand in your code.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Another good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using *creole.xml*. I have tried with SentenceSplitter but it is giving me incorrect sentences. So, I am using RegexSentenceSplitter instead.
Added few lines in creole.xml-

```
<RESOURCE>
    <CLASS>gate.creole.splitter.RegexSentenceSplitter</CLASS>
    <PARAMETER NAME="externalSplitListURL" DEFAULT="file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/external-split-patterns.txt" COMMENT="The URL to the custom external-split-patterns.txt" SUFFIXES="txt;text">java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER NAME="internalSplitListURL" DEFAULT="file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/internal-split-patterns.txt" COMMENT="The URL to the custom internal-split-patterns.txt" SUFFIXES="txt;text">java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER NAME="nonSplitListURL" DEFAULT="file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/non-split-patterns.txt" COMMENT="The URL to the custom non-split-patterns.txt" SUFFIXES="txt;text">java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
</RESOURCE>
```

Then loading *ANNIE_with_defaults.gapp* from backend code as shown in the question.

**Hope it may be helpful.**